# how to find 8?16?32? bit image in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

How to find whether the image loaded is 8 bit or 16 or 32?

And what is the range of values for " Lab color space " for 32 bit image ?

ANd what happens for the range for Lab 16 bit image?

Answer (score 2):

It is simple to find the format of a matrix.

```
cv::Mat src = cv::imread(filename, cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
switch (src.depth()) {
case CV_8U: // 8 bit unsigned
case CV_16U: // 16 bit unsigned
case CV_32U: // 32 bit unsigned
case CV_32F: // float
case CV_64F: // double
}
```

You can also enfore a format, e.g.

```
cv::Mat1f mat = src;
```

Note that in this example, we assume `src.channels() == 1`.

Comment: any idea abt LAB @ypnos